# Не могу изменить отображение элемента select?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть **select элемент** с *начальным заголовком* Gender нажимая на который можно выбрать *male* или *female*.

Как изменить размер и цвет, **только заголовка Gender**, *не option Gender*  ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<select class="mt-2 pl-4  custom-select user-data" name="gender">
    <option>Gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
select {
  color: blue !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow !important;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' v…0 4 5'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23343a40' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E);
}

option {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<select class="mt-2 pl-4 custom-select user-data" name="gender">
    <option>Gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Но стрелки перестали отображатся

Comment: @a_mine, дело в том, что если убрать желтый фон, то видим, что стоит по дефолту: `bacground-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' v…0 4 5'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23343a40' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E);` **Изменил**

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Css Optgroup http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-izmenit-vid-tega-optgroup-cherez-stili

Или используйте отдельный css класс для этой опции.

Comment: Так изменить нужно не опцию, а текущее значение в поле..

Comment: Тогда применяйте классы к select при условии value === "значение поля Gender". Или Вы толкуете просто о любой опции, отображаемой в данный момент в select?

Comment: Ну я думал, автор имел ввиду, чтобы просто изменить текст, который есть на текущий момент в этом поле и наверное это касается всех выбранных значений..

Comment: Тогда просто применить css класс к select и все дела.